# Filemaker .Net Driver

Tags: .net, ado.net

I am not familiar with Filemaker, but I have inherited a Filemaker (I think v3) database.
Is there an ADO.net or odbc driver I can use to extract data?

Answer (score 1):

There's an [ODBC](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/odbc_ess.20.11.html#1027942) client driver.

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker 3 is way way ancient. Current version is 10, and it is light years ahead of FM3. You can connect via ODBC, also to Filemaker Server you can connect with PHP, more.